# is it possible to concat arguments to a command line using backquotes ?

Tags: ruby, command-line, command-line-interface

I would like to execute an OS command from my ruby script but I want to add an argument from a ruby variable.

I know that's possible by using keyword *system* like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
directory = '/home/paulgreg/'
system 'ls ' + directory
```

but is that possible by using the "backquotes or backticks syntax" ?
(I mean by using that syntax : `ls`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that will just concatenate the output from `ls` and the contents of `directory`.

But you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
directory = '/home/paulgreg/'
`ls #{directory}`
```

Answer (score 6):

```
`ls #{directory}`
```

isn't very safe because you're going to run into problems with path names that have spaces in them.

It's safer to do something like this:

```
directory = '/home/paulgreg/'

args = []
args << "/bin/ls"
args << directory

system(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nick is right, but there is no need to assemble the args piecewise:

```
directory = '/Volumes/Omg a space/'
system('/bin/ls', directory)
```